# Topology induced by Uniformity?

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Let $f:(X,U) \to (Y,U^{'})$ is a mapping , then $ f $ is uniformly continuous iff $ U^{''}\subset U $ where $ U^{''} $ is the induced uniform structure on $ X $ by $ f $ .

Comment: What is your question? And what is your definition of 'uniformly continuous'?

Comment: A uniformly continuous function is defined as one where inverse images of entourages are again entourages, or equivalently, one where the inverse images of uniform covers are again uniform covers.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is a consequence of the minimality part of the definition of "induced uniform structure", or otherwise a direct consequence of the definition that all sets $\{(f \times f)^{-1}[O]: O \in \mathcal{U}'\}$ is a base for it and this base consists of entourages already in $\mathcal{U}$ if $f$ is uniformly continuous!